# Intellij fix Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, intellij-plugin

I have always this problem on intellij .
when i want to commit new changes on SVN , intellij show

> Performing VCS Refresh

page and got too long time to show commit window .
I debug this problem and found this :

```
2019-12-15 10:50:36,460 [94334589]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../jsondoc/webjars/jsondoc-ui-webjar' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,543 [94334672]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/mah454/Programming/Java/moke/web/target/classes/com/myapp/crm/model/business/agreement' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,615 [94334744]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/js/plugin/ckeditor/plugins/find' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,675 [94334804]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/js/plugin/ckeditor/skins' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,735 [94334864]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/controller/vo/service/shared' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,794 [94334923]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/Documentation' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,853 [94334982]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/model/business/agreement' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,912 [94335041]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/model/credit/terminal' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:36,971 [94335100]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/util/cron/services' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,030 [94335159]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/util/vo' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,089 [94335218]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../js/plugin/ckeditor/plugins/flash' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,148 [94335277]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/js/plugin/ckeditor/samples/assets/inlineall' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,207 [94335336]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../img/favicon' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,266 [94335395]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/mah454/Programming/Java/moke/web/target/classes/com/myapp/crm/util/nosql/mongo' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,324 [94335453]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/js/plugin/jquery-validate' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,383 [94335512]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/crm/util/thumbnailer/util' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,442 [94335571]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/img/favicon' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,502 [94335631]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../js/plugin/morris' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,560 [94335689]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../js/plugin/bootstrap-slider' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,622 [94335751]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/mah454/Programming/Java/moke/web/target/classes/com/myapp/shiro/realm' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,682 [94335811]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../css' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,743 [94335872]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/mah454/Programming/Java/moke/web/target/classes/resources/i18n' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,802 [94335931]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../WEB-INF/classes/com' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,861 [94335990]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/mah454/Programming/Java/moke/web/target/classes/com/myapp/crm/model/notification' was not found.
2019-12-15 10:50:37,923 [94336052]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node '.../doc/ajax/js/plugin/bootstrap-timepicker' was not found.
```

How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, this will be fixed in 2019.3.1
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224516